# Typo3 7: Change fluid_styled_content textmedia video width

Tags: php, typo3, fluid

I want to change the default size of a textmedia video in the frontend. Right now if I upload a new video (format: vimeo), for some reason {column.dimensions.width} is 490 - is there a way to change this via typoscript? Where does that come from?

I'd be thankful for any hints!

Answer (score 2):

This comes from the `calculateMediaWidthsAndHeights` function from the class `GalleryProcessor` in the system extension frontend. The width depends on some facts:

- Maximum width of the media element (`maxGalleryWidth`)

  This property is set in TypoScript. The path:
  tt_content.textmedia.dataProcessing.20.maxGalleryWidth
- Width for each media element. It is set inside the element. See the image below:

[image: Media Adjustments, width of each element. In the calculation its name is equalMediaWidth]

- How many columns do you have. "Number of Columns" set to 2 in default.

The logic is like: you have a max size for your "gallery", because each textmedia element is a gallery of media elements. The function calculates how many elements you want to show in one row, caped with the max width of the element.

So you have two solution:

1) You try to adjust the TypoScript value for `maxGalleryWidth` and the Max Element Width

or

2) You make your own fluid template which one in case of 1 video renders it just the way you want.

`fluid_styled_content` is very flexible in this matter.